# Spring boot app starts slow without internet connection on Yocto Linux

Tags: java, spring-boot, yocto, inetaddress

I have a Spring Boot application running on a Yocto Linux that must work also without external internet connection from the network router. The Spring app is accessible within the LAN from other devices.
When the router internet cable is unplugged, the app starts 3 minutes slower as with internet.

**spring boot log:**

```
[main] WARN o.s.boot.StartupInfoLogger-InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() 
took 20020 milliseconds to respond. Please verify your network configuration.
```

**cat /etc/hostname**

```
myapp
```

**cat /etc/os-release**

```
ID="myapp"
NAME="myapp"
VERSION="4.14-sumo (sumo)"
VERSION_ID="4.14-sumo"
PRETTY_NAME="myapp 4.14-sumo (sumo)"
```

**cat /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1 myapp
```

Comment: so `/etc/hosts` should rather be: `127.0.0.1  myapp localhost.localdomain localhost` ... `::1     myapp localhost` (!) ... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))